# NDK-build GLuint does not name a type when trying to compile

Tags: android, opengl-es, compilation, android-ndk, sdl-2

So apparently im not too sure how to include Open GL in my SDL application

I have:

```
if _ANDROID_
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <GLES2/glext.h>
```

but when I use **GLUint** I get

> GLuint does not name a type

**My android.mk includes**

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -llog
```

and i am building for android platform 10 (** **)

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-10 
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a armeabi x86
```

So i am not too sure what i am doing wrong

(Added the rest of the file that is having problems:)

```
#pragma once
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <cassert>

#include "vec2.h"
#include "vec3.h"
#include "vec4.h"
#include "mat4.h"
#include "transformations.h"

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#include <windows.h>
#include <glew.h>
#include <gl\gl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#endif

#if __APPLE__
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2_image/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL2_mixer/SDL_mixer.h>
#endif

#if __ANDROID__
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>
#endif

// vec2 *screen;
/*const*/ // int sw;
/*const*/ // int sh;

#if __IPHONEOS__ || __ANDROID__
#define MOBILE 1
#endif

#if __MACOSX__ || __WINDOWS__ || __LINUX__
#define PC 1
#endif

#if __IPHONEOS__
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
inline void glBindVertexArray(GLuint id1) {
   glBindVertexArrayOES(id1);
}
inline void glGenVertexArrays(GLsizei n, GLuint *ids) {
   glGenVertexArraysOES(n, ids);
}
inline void glDeleteVertexArrays(GLsizei n, const GLuint *ids) {
   glDeleteVertexArraysOES(n, ids);
}
#elif TARGET_OS_MAC
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glext.h>
inline void glBindVertexArray(GLuint id1) {
   glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(id1);
}
inline void glGenVertexArrays(GLsizei n, GLuint *ids) {
   glGenVertexArraysAPPLE(n, ids);
}
inline void glDeleteVertexArrays(GLsizei n, const GLuint *ids) {
   glDeleteVertexArraysAPPLE(n, ids);
}

#elif __ANDROID__
#include <GLES3/gl3.h>
#include <GLES3/gl3ext.h>
    inline void glBindVertexArray(GLuint id1) {
        glBindVertexArrayOES(id1);
    }
    inline void glGenVertexArrays(GLsizei n, GLuint *ids) {
        glGenVertexArraysOES(n, ids);
    }
    inline void glDeleteVertexArrays(GLsizei n, const GLuint *ids) {
        glDeleteVertexArraysOES(n, ids);
    }
#endif // ANDROID


inline string get_path(string filename) {
   char *base = SDL_GetBasePath();
   string path(base + filename);
   SDL_free(base);
   //cout << "getting path " << path << endl;
   return path;
}

using namespace std;
```

Comment: Is `_ANDROID_` a typo? The define should be `__ANDROID__`. Also, `#ifdef`, not `if`...

Comment: C++ is case sensitive - if you're using `GLUint`, it would not be found, because the type is `GLuint`.

Comment: Thanks @DanAlbert You were right with that error. But now im getting 'glDeleteVertexArraysOES was not declared in this scope, and that type is used in the same file exactly after the __android__ stuff and adding gl2.h and gl2ext.h. I read somewhere that this type is not supported in gl2 so I tried with GL3 and I get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: I added the rest of that file. It does compile normally for windows and IOS, but I just cant get it to compile with the android's ndk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using

```
APP_STL := c++_static
```

instead of

```
#APP_STL := gnustl_static
```